# Microsoft Graph profile endpoint does not return the user's name

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm retrieving user information using the graph API (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`), but I'm only getting very little information:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "id": "e163a120378.....",
  "userPrincipalName": "myemail@example.com"
}
```

(Omitting properties with null values)

I'm sure that this user has at least a name (and probably some other properties), and I am expecting it to be included in the response, but it's not.

The access token used for the request was requested with scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`, using the token enpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`. I've tried many other scopes, without results.

How do I retrieve user information with more details, like a name?

Comment: Is this happening for all users on this tenant or only this one?

Comment: This seems to happen for all users

Comment: Are you seeing the same result from both your​ app and [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)?

Comment: Yes, although the Graph Explorer also includes "givenName": "",
    "surname": "". The account has both a given name and a surname configured.

Comment: Are you using one of the SDKs or making HTTP calls directly? Also, have you attempted to add these fields to a select statement (`?$select=givenName,surname`)?

Comment: I'm making HTTP calls directly. Adding the `$select` parameter like you said doesn't change anything.

Comment: BTW, the accounts I'm testing with are set up through account.microsoft.com. I'm assuming this type of accounts can also be queried through the graph API?

Comment: @Tom This API do support for the Microsoft Account. I can reproduce this issue when I create a Microsoft Account. It seems that this REST need to take some time to make it work for the changing for some property.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comment

Comment: The Microsoft Graph API works well for me for the exist Microsoft account. However after I register a new Microsoft Account,I changed the sure name and last name, but these two properties returns the empty string. It seems the new account need some time to make it work for the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT It certainly not a matter of time; the account I'm testing with hasn't changed recently.

Comment: I'm able to replicate both scenarios. My personal MSA (quite old) returns all of the name fields (given, sur, display) but a newly created MSA is returning empty givenName and surName along with a null displayName. I will give it time for any caches to expire and test again.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you'll want to update this account's profile with First Name and Last Name via https://profile.live.com. Once populated, these values will surface within Graph.

There are multiple systems backing Microsoft Accounts. Graph is pulling the profile data from Outlook.com. The https://profile.live.com site holds the Outlook Profile which that Graph is reading from. Once a user visits Outlook.com, all of the profile data is provisioned and then synced with https://account.microsoft.com. Prior to that however, the Profile isn't fully populated.

Comment: I could do this with my personal account, but it's not very realistic to expect all users of my system to update their account at profile.live.com, is it?

Comment: I agree but just to clarify, I don't believe they need to update their profile so much as they need to login to Outlook.com at least once before the profile populates.